# $http updated data in localStorage after every week

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, local-storage, angular-local-storage

Using $http in angular we get data for a week, the data won't change for a week, Every sunday the data gets updated in $http.get, So my question is, the new data will also get updated in localstorage?

For my request.success(), I use

```
 window.localStorage['storageName'] = angular.toJson(data);
```

Then I can access the data in localstorage by

```
var accessData = window.localStorage['storageName'];
```

Comment: Is this a solution?  https://github.com/toddmotto/vault

Answer (score -1):

When the AJAX call happens, and your .success() callback is called, that will replace the localStorage item.

Comment: Could someone please explain why this was downvoted? I genuinely want to know so I can learn.

Comment: You need to improve your answer. It seems like its more of a comment. A proper answer in this case should contain a code that clearly explains how OPs question will be resolved.